# AbstractMethodError in Receiver class org.ajoberstar.grgit.operation.OpenOp while trying to build springfox using gradle

Tags: java, gradle, swagger, springfox, grgit

After cloning the https://github.com/springfox/springfox springfix repo , when i try to build the project using `./gradlew clean build -i` command, i always get AbstractMethodError.

```
* What went wrong:
Receiver class org.ajoberstar.grgit.operation.OpenOp does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract setProperty(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V of interface groovy.lang.GroovyObject.

* Exception is:
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.ajoberstar.grgit.operation.OpenOp does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract setProperty(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V of interface groovy.lang.GroovyObject.
        at org.ajoberstar.grgit.internal.OpSyntax$_mapOperation_closure1.doCall(OpSyntax.groovy:17)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.ajoberstar.grgit.internal.OpSyntax.mapOperation(OpSyntax.groovy:16)
        at org.ajoberstar.grgit.internal.OpSyntax$mapOperation.callStatic(Unknown Source)
        at org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit.open(Grgit.groovy)
        at org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit$open.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.ajoberstar.grgit.gradle.GrgitPlugin.apply(GrgitPlugin.groovy:17)
        at org.ajoberstar.grgit.gradle.GrgitPlugin.apply(GrgitPlugin.groovy)


JAVA version: 
java version "11.0.19" 2023-04-18 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.19+9-LTS-224)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.19+9-LTS-224, mixed mode)
```

gradle used in gradle-wrapper.properties file is :

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip
```

In build.gradle file inside plugins {} , it has:

```
id "org.ajoberstar.grgit" version "4.0.2"
id "org.ajoberstar.git-publish" version "3.0.0-rc.1"
```

In gradle.org site, i can see this post asking about same error but no resolution mentioned there : https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-6-9-2-started-failing-without-changes-receiver-class-org-ajoberstar-grgit-operation-openop-does-not-define-or-inherit-an-implementation-of-the-resolved-method-abstract-setproperty/42172

Similar issue raised in springfox github issues section as well, but no reply there as well. - https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/4005

Can you please help if you also have faced it and how did you get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and updated the build to use gradle-7 instead of gradle-6 and it resolved itself.